# How to return reference from BlueprintImplementableEvent?

Tags: c++, unreal-4, unreal, blueprints

I've got a C++ component and I want to have function which will be implemented in Blueprint like this:

```
UFUNCTION(BlueprintImplementableEvent)
Stats& GetStats();
```

But this doesn't compile, I get the following error:

> overload function differs only by return type from

and Unreal generates function inside .gen.cpp looking like this:

```
Stats Component::GetStats()
{
// ...
}
```

Stats is USTRUCT

Comment: I could be wrong but it looks like Unreal is expecting a return value (whatever stats you're getting from GetStats) and you're not giving it one in the UFUNCTION call.

Answer (score 1):

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////
//By reference
//////////////////////////////////////////////
//.h
UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable)
    void GetStats(const FStats& stats);

//.cpp
void YOURCLASS::GetStats(const FStats& stats)
{
    stats = FStats();
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////
//Copy
//////////////////////////////////////////////
//.h
UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable)
    FStats GetStats();

//.cpp
FStats YOURCLASS::GetStats()
{
    return FStats();
}
```

Comment: No, instance of Stats is created in blueprint and I need to return it from blueprint to c++.

Comment: @devalone then use the reference method.